# Unresponsive socket read buffer

Tags: java, c#, sockets, tcp, network-programming

I am trying to send data to one of my servers and receive an ACK back from it. However, the processing gets hung up when waiting for a response from the server. I know for a fact that there is a connection because I can see the data reaching the server. I also know that the server is outputting data correctly because my C# client is receiving data back from the server. I will note that this client is running on a centOS virtual machine. The server is a remote windows machine. I wouldn't imagine that there would be an issue due to the virtual environment because I am able to use an SNMP java client (SNMP4j package) to make calls to a remote server. I believe my server is outputting raw binary too, but I would expect to see some kind of output either way.

```
// A Java program for a Client 
 import java.net.*; 
 import java.io.*; 

public class Client 
{ 
// initialize socket and input output streams 
private Socket socket            = null; 
private DataInputStream  input   = null; 
private DataOutputStream out     = null; 
private DataInputStream  serveroutput= null;

// constructor to put ip address and port 
public Client(String address, int port) 
{ 
    // establish a connection 
    try
    { 
        socket = new Socket(address, port); 
        System.out.println("Connected"); 

        // takes input from terminal 
        input  = new DataInputStream(System.in); 

        // sends output to the socket 
        out    = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream()); 
        serveroutput = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
    } 
    catch(UnknownHostException u) 
    { 
        System.out.println(u); 
    } 
    catch(IOException i) 
    { 
        System.out.println(i); 
    } 

    // string to read message from input 
    String line = ""; 

    // keep reading until "Over" is input 
    while (!line.equals("Over")) 
    { 
        try
        { 
            line = input.readLine(); 
            out.writeUTF(line); 
            System.out.println(serveroutput.readLine())
        } 
        catch(IOException i) 
        { 
            System.out.println(i); 
        } 
    } 

    // close the connection 
    try
    { 
        input.close(); 
        out.close(); 
        socket.close(); 
    } 
    catch(IOException i) 
    { 
        System.out.println(i); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Is the response from the server a *line*? This code will wait until it is able to read a line, so if the server is not sending lines, it will wait forever (or until the server closes the connection). You need to make sure that both the server and the client agree on what constitutes a complete messages. Here, your client code considers a line, and only a line, to be a complete message. Does the server?

Comment: That might be a good point. How would i make certain that it is indeed a line being sent? I noticed that when I send messages to my server it prefixes the message with \0 and postfixes with \n. Should i try adding those characters?

Comment: Does the peer really understand `writeUTF()`? If it's C# it won't.

Comment: @MarquisofLorne well all I can say to that is that C# server is able to receive a JSON string from this Java client

Comment: @xScub Who wrote the server? Is there a specification for the protocol used or do you have to reverse engineer it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could be great if you would share the otherside codes. *(sorry cannot comment yet)*
Try use something else over `writeUTF()`, simply maybe a `PrintStream`, as mentioned by @marquis-of-lorne `(read|write)UTF` may be confusing by the peer.

Also this might be a good practice to `flush()` out the output from both side when there is nothing else to send to make sure data is sent completely.

You may also try `BufferedReader` over `InputDataStream` as you are trying to read lines. `readLine()` from `InputDataStream` is deprecated.